# What counts as powerups?

Tags: temple-run-2

There is an objective that requires scoring 1 million points without powerups.

What counts as powerups? Does it include the bonus you get for filling the power bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only powerups that break this are the Shield, Boost, and Coin Magnet. Activating anything other than that will still enable you to get this objective. You can also pick up gems and coins without fear.

Comment: What about power-ups gained from the power meter? Do they count?

Comment: I believe the power meter counts.

Comment: How about the +50 coins and +500 points power meter rewards? Also, does getting your power meter filled but not using the reward counts? I just never seem to get it...

Answer (score 1):

The circles in the air are power-ups, as is the power bar. You can still pick up gems, coins, and artifacts, without worrying about failing. Also, I belive if you die, and use the wheel, It will count as a power-up if you get a boost, coin magnet, ect.